# How to take backup of SQL Server in AWS?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, database-backups

How to take backup of SQL Server in AWS ? Is there any other option other than native backup ?

Comment: Are you using RDS or a custom installation of sql on a ec2 instance ?

Comment: I am using RDS. Is their any other way of taking backup.

Comment: After loging into the rds vai management studio it is not allowing me to take backup  in  Files>task>backup do you have any idea about this please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) supports native backup and restore for Microsoft SQL Server databases using full backup files (.bak files). You can import and export SQL Server databases in a single, easily portable file. You can create a full backup of your on-premises database, store it on Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3), and then restore the backup file onto an existing Amazon RDS DB instance running SQL Server.

There are mainly three components you will need to setup

- An Amazon S3 bucket to store your backup files.
- An AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role to access the
  bucket.
- The SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE option added to an option group on your
  DB instance.

Reference- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-for-sql-server-support-for-native-backuprestore-to-amazon-s3/

Comment: After loging into the rds vai management studio it is not allowing me to take backup in Files>task>backup do you have any idea about this please suggest

Comment: To take backup from SQL Server Management Studio, follow this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-for-sql-server-support-for-native-backuprestore-to-amazon-s3/ . As far as I am aware it will allow you only to take the backup on a s3 location. Do not forget to set iam role before you perform this.

Comment: TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Backup failed for Server .  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=14.0.17177.0+((SSMS_Rel).170803-0429)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Backup+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: BACKUP DATABASE permission denied in database 'SocietyDB'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: is their any permission issue?

Comment: Yeah, as I said above , you need to create an IAM role for this. Example is there on the reference website.